# Issue controlling script flow

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I'm new to shell scripting, my script appears to be okay, but its the flow that I'm having an issue controlling. Could someone point out what silly mistake I've made please.

```
#! /bin/sh

echo "Are you sure youx want to delete $1? Answer y or n"
read ans
echo $ans
if $ans = "y"|"Y"
then
    mv $1 /home/parallels/dustbin
    echo "File $1 has been deleted"
else echo "File $1 has not been deleted"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your if condition like this:

```
if [ "$ans" = "y" -o "$ans" = "Y" ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful response!

Comment: You are welcome..If the solution has worked for you, accept the answer. In case of multiple answers working for you, accept the one that best suits your problem...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your script.  Some are serious, some are less so.

First, the serious problems.

As guru suggested, you need to use square brackets to surround your `if` condition.  This is because `if` only tests for the output of a condition, it doesn't perform actual string comparisons.  Traditionally, a program called `/bin/test`, which was also called `/bin/[` took care of that.  These days, that functionality is built in to the shell, but `/bin/sh` still behaves as if it's a separate program.

In fact, you can do interesting things with `if` when you *don't* use square brackets for your condition.  For example, `if grep -q 'RE' /path/to/file; then` is quite common.  The `grep -q` command issues no output, but simply returns a "success" or "fail" that is detected by `if`.

Second serious problem is that you are echoing a status that may or may not be true.  I call this a serious problem because ... well, log messages simply shouldn't make false claims.  If the permissions are wrong for the file in `$1`, or the filename contains a space, then your `mv` command will fail, but the message will claim that it did not.  More on this later.

Next, the less serious problems.

These are mostly style and optimization things.

First off, `read` on most platforms includes a `-p` option that lets you specify a prompt.  Use this, and you don't need to include an `echo` command.

Second, your indenting makes it hard to see what the `if` construct is wrapping.  This isn't a huge problem in a program this small, but as you grow, you REALLY want to follow consistent standards.

Third, you can probably get more flexibility in multiple-choice questions like this if you use `case` statements instead of `if`.

After all that, here's how I'd write this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = "-y" ]; then
  ans=y
  shift
elif [ -t 0 ]; then
  read -p "Are you sure you want to delete '$1' (y/N) ? " ans
fi

case "$ans" in
  Y*|y*)
    retval=0
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
      retval=64
      echo "ERROR: you didn't specify a filename." >&2
    if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
      retval=66
      echo "ERROR: file '$1' not found!" >&2
    elif mv "$1" /home/parallels/dustbin/; then
      echo "File '$1' has been deleted" >&2
    else
      retval=$?
      echo "ERROR: file '$1' could not be deleted!" >&2
    fi
    ;;
  *)
    echo "ABORT: file '$1' has not been deleted" >&2
    retval=4
    ;;
esac

exit $retval
```

Aside from what's mentioned above, here are some things in this code snippet:

- `[ "$1" = "-y" ]` - if the user specifies a `-y` option, then we behave as if the question was answered with a "yes".
- `[ -t 0 ]` - this tests whether we are on an interactive terminal.  If we are, then it makes sense to ask questions with `read`.
- `Y*|y*)` - in a case statement, this matches any string that begins with an upper or lower case "y".  Valid affirmative responses would therefore be "Y", "yes", "yellow", etc.
- `[ ! -f "$1" ]` - this tests whether the file exists.  You can `man test` or `man sh` to see the various tests available in shell.  (`-f` may not be the most appropriate for you.)
- `>&2` - at the end of a line, sends its output to "standard error" instead of "standard out".  This changes how output will be handled by pipes, cron, etc.  Errors and log data are often sent to stderr, so that stdout can be dedicated to a program's actual output.
- `mv "$1" ...` - The filename is in quotes.  This protects you in case the filename has special characters like spaces in it.
- `$retval` - the values for this came from a best guess of the closest item in [`man sysexits`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3/sysexits/).
- `retval=$?` - this is the exit status of the most recently executed command.  In this case, that means we're assigning `mv`'s exit status to the variable `$retval`, so that if `mv` failed, the whole script reports the reason for the fail, as far as `mv` is concerned.

Comment: only question I got is if it would be necessary to also return error codes from the script when for example the `mv` fails (this being currently hidden by the `echo ERROR..` that would return ok)

Comment: @GermanGarcia - yes, that might be a good idea, especially if the script is crafted so that it can be wrapped by other scripts.  I've updated the answer to include more "learning".  :-)

Comment: nice, pedagogical answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the user response to either case and just check it for respective case like

```
read ans
ans=${ans,,}  # make 'ans' lowercase, or use ${ans^^} for making it uppercase
if [ "$ans" = "y" ]
then
   ....
fi
```

Comment: This method of converting to lower case only works in bash.  The OP's script runs `/bin/sh` - we don't know whether bash is also available, but even if it is, your answer should probably specify bash as a requirement, since bash uses POSIX behaviour when invoked as `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the perfect code with error handling included

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Are you sure you want to delete $1? Answer y or n"
read ans
echo $ans

if [ $ans == "y" ] || [ $ans == "Y" ]
then
    if [ -f $1 ]
    then
           mv $1 /home/parallels/dustbin
           echo "File $1 has been deleted"         
    else
           echo " File $1 is not found"
    fi
else 
    echo "File $1 has not been deleted"
fi
```